# Lossless convert WMA to WAV on a mac

Tags: conversion

Anyone know of any software that can convert wma files to wav without any loss of quality e.g. loseless conversion?

Answer (score 9):

Converting a from wma file to wav is technically un-compressing it.  You will not be able to regain the quality lost from the original compression, but you shouldn't lose any additional quality as long as the algorithm of the conversion software is decent.

[ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) should work well for your needs.

Edit:  (Thanks to @evilsoup for the command line given in the comment below)

For converting a directory recursively, you'll want to use find, either with the -exec option, or piping to ffmpeg via xargs. If you want to get fancy, you could install GNU parallel and perform multiple conversions simultaneously. A basic example would be:

```
find . -type f -name '*.wma' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" "${0%.wma}.wav"' '{}' \;
```

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/521513/why-doesnt-this-for-loop-work) for some related information.

Comment: Thanks for this. Any change of how I would use command line to convert recursively a directory and maintain the directory structure. I have a few thousand files, and I'm not a command line expert so any additional info about ffmpeg would be useful

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with the command line on the Mac.  I was only able to find a few examples from Linux and Windows.  I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @FriendOfGeorge FYI, I think the Linux command line is quite similar to the Mac command line (for basic stuff at least).

Comment: For converting a directory recursively, you'll want to use find, either with the `-exec` option, or piping to ffmpeg via `xargs`. If you want to get fancy, you could install GNU `parallel` and perform multiple conversions simultaneously. A basic example would be: `find . -type f -name '*.wma' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" "${0%.wma}.wav"' '{}' \;` - see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/521513/why-doesnt-this-for-loop-work) for some related information.

Answer (score 2):

WAV is an uncompressed format. Unless you are merging tracks, reducing the sample rate, or lowering the bit depth (all unlikely to happen by accident), a plain conversion to WAV will always be lossless. Of course, this will not remove noise introduced by the lossy compression on the source material. Basically, any program you find will suffice.

Comment: Unfortunately the source is WMA, so I was to convert to wav without further compression.

Answer (score -3):

I would like to follow [**this detailed guide**](http://www.faasoft.com/articles/wma-to-wav-on-windows-and-mac.html) to **convert WMA to WAV**.

But before the conversion, you should know that from an article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format):

WMA is a format with lossy compression. While WAV is uncompressed audio formats.

So the conversion will do not harm to the quality.

Comment: One of a million sites wanting you to spend 50 bucks to buy a front-end to existing functionality.